# convert bootstrap 4 to 5 navbar two tows

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

want to convert bootstrap 4 to bootstrap 5 two rows of the navbar

I found this code
https://codepen.io/metismiao/pen/bQBoyw
it's excellent for me but it is with bootstrap 4
but I use bootstrap 5 and I have tried to convert it but I have some issue

```
.navbar-brand{
  padding-top: 0;
}
@media(min-width:768px)
{
 
  .navbar-first-row{
   height:50px;
    background-color:B5428E;
  }
 
  .navbar-top-left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:42B55B;
  }

  .navbar-top-right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:15px;
    background-color:E82985;
    }
  .navbar-bottom-left{
    background-color:A5B60C;
  }
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-first-row"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/128x50"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-bottom-left">
        <li><a href="#">1-800-233-1111</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">lemo@info.net</a></li> 
      </ul>
      
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-bottom-right">
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Login</a></li> 
      </ul>
      
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-top-right">
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="#" class="bg-success">Call now </a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

this code

https://codepen.io/metismiao/pen/bQBoyw

to convert it to bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

That codepen uses absolute positioning for *absolutely* no reason.

"Converting" an older bootstrap layout to a new version is best achieved by starting fresh to create the same look and behavior. Especially when the old code uses some funky methods to achieve a very simple layout.

[If you read the Bootstrap documentation on Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works) you can just copy [one of their examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#nav) to start. To get "two rows" you wrap the `navbar-nav` in a `container-fluid` with no padding, followed by a `row` with no gutters and use `.row-cols-*` to quickly set the number of `columns`.

With your three `navbar-nav`s neatly tucked in their columns, you use a [Bootstrap's Flex Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) class to position the second `navbar` to the right with `.justify-content-end`.

All that's left is apply the correct `breakpoint` classes where required, in my example I used `md`. So at the medium breakpoint, the `navbar-nav`s will stack nicely inside the `collapse`.

And that's how easy Bootstrap can make it for you.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row g-0 row-cols-md-2">
          <div class="col-md navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md d-md-flex justify-content-end navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link bg-success-subtle" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```